# Ubuntu on windows 8

Tags: windows

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Sony Vaio laptop from bootable pendrive. During installation there was only 1MB free space on hard drives. So I installed it on hard drive with no free space. but on installation my windows 8 is not working properly.

I can only access it can't play music or other application. Third hard drive is not accessible from windows, its name has been changed. on clicking it it suggest to format.
I am not getting system restore point on windows 8 to revert setting. please help how to resolve issue so that I can run both windows 8 and Ubuntu on same system.

One of the possible reason that I can not access one hard drive is because Ubuntu is installed on it and to access it ext4 file system is needed. But if I install ext4 software can I access my files again? why is my programs(VLC) etc are not working?

Here's what my Ubuntu installation shows in installation type

```
Device     type Mount point Format? size       Used      System
/dev/sda   fat32                    277MB      33MB
/dev/sda2  ntfs                     1545MB     Unkonwn
/dev/sda3  efil                     272MB      272MB
/dev/sda4                           134MB      Unknown
/dev/sda5  swap                 178640MB       0MB
/dev/sda6  ext4                 161060MB       Unknown
/dev/sda7  ntfs                 161060MB       5884MB   Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04)
free space                           1MB
/dev/sda8  ntfs                 214747MB       Unknown
free space                          1 MB
/dev/sda9  ext4                  32417MB       733MB
free space                           0MB
```

In Windows on start shows explorer.exe - Bad image 
There is C drive, Drive E Drive F and Drive G.

I am unable to access drive F nor can I play any music or other files in windows.

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to play vlc player now it works, sound, video are working now. But still can't access drive F

Comment: From the above, we can't tell which device Windows calls C, D, etc. You will have to figure that out from the device size, file system type, perhaps brand. It is normal that Windows doesn't recognize Linux drives, and instead offers to format them. Please don't do that. You won't be able to play files from a Linux drive in Windows, whereas the other way around will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you might have installed the drivers or the music software on the drive on which you have installed the ubuntu now. try to reinstall the software and audio drivers. normally ubuntu file system can't be opened from the windows os. but fat32 file system can be opened from ext4(ubuntu) file system. the 3rd drive which you are trying to open might be installed with ubuntu. please check it can be seen in the partition manager with ext4 file system then it is the ubuntu installed drive. the installation of the ubuntu can't be reverted. it is not a package installation with in the windows. it is a seperate os.

If you have problems with the existing working of the you laptop. then back up your data in a external disk and reinstall what you want.

Comment: how do I access my content from Hard drive?

Comment: have you checked to login the windows try it. know the file system of the all drives in your HDD. and also let me know which drive is having fat32 and which one is ext4. the data in the ext4 file system partition is already lost whcih you might have saved while using windows

Comment: The windows drive F was not accessible from windows, I did not installed ubuntu on free space but instead on same drive. Do you mean ext4 from linux lead to loss of data?

Comment: How Can I prevent dialogue of format drive from appearing in windows so as to prevent formatting that drive by accidently clicking it?